# Angular $cookies saved as Object. Can not fetch the object as JSON

Tags: node.js, json, angularjs, cookies, cookiestore

After calling an api i got json data as follows which i stored using a variable.

```
$scope.twotap_builtin_cart = {"sites":{"571fb46730bb1f373d00bdb4":{"info":{"name":"Overstock","url":"overstock.com"},"currency_format":"$AMOUNT","coupon_support":false,"gift_card_support":false,"checkout_support":["noauthCheckout"],"shipping_countries_support":["United States of America"],"billing_countries_support":["United States of America"],"shipping_options":{"cheapest":"Default shipping option"},"returns":"<p><span style=\"font-size:16px\"><strong>Overstock Return Policy</strong></span></p>\r\n\r\n<p>description ......... </p>\r\n","add_to_cart":{"a6eda98b2e60363a67efb985ef622cea":{"clean_url":"http://www.overstock.com/7281112/product.html?CID=207442","weight":"1000","status":"done","required_fields":{"quantity":{"data":[{"input_type":"text","input_name":"INPUT"}]}},"discounted_price":null,"original_price":null,"pickup_support":false,"url":"http://www.overstock.com/7281112/product.html?TRACK=affcjfeed&CID=207442&fp=F","required_field_values":{},"required_field_names":["quantity"],"categories":["Sports & Toys","Toys & Hobbies","Games & Puzzles","Board Games"],"alt_images":["http://ak1.ostkcdn.com/images/products/7281112/Perisphere-and-Trylon-The-Britannia-Compendium-of-Games-f17b48f6-8c81-4a0e-af12-fa2e3d97ac25_320.jpg"],"image":"http://ak1.ostkcdn.com/images/products/7281112/Perisphere-and-Trylon-The-Britannia-Compendium-of-Games-f17b48f6-8c81-4a0e-af12-fa2e3d97ac25_600.jpg","price":"$37.49","title":"Perisphere and Trylon The Britannia Compendium of Games"}}}},"user_id":null,"unknown_urls":[],"cart_id":"5785d83c493bfb7f2a352cde","notes":null,"country":"us","stored_field_values":{}}
```

Then I saved this data inside cookies using following function of angular.

```
$cookies['xxx'] = $scope.twotap_builtin_cart;
```

Now, when i tried to retrieve this data from cookies, it showed me as an Object. I tried to print it inside console it showed object Object. But I need json formatted data.

```
var t = $cookies['xxx'];
console.log(t);
$scope.recentItemsx = angular.toJson(t); // converted to json
console.log($scope.recentItemsx);
console.log(JSON.parse($cookies['xxx']));
```

I tried anglar.toJson and json.parse function. Nothing can give me json formatted data. Moreover, I tried with cookie store to save angular data.

```
$cookieStore.put('recentx',$scope.twotap_builtin_cart);
```

Then i tried to print from cookie store.

```
console.log($cookieStore.get('recentx'));
```

It give me output [object Object]. I can not work with this. I need json data for ng-repeat purpose
I can not putObject(key) or getObject(key) function because, I am using angular version greater than 1.4

Comment: please share a fiddle so we can reproduce it and help you out

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.stringify(t) to convert it to a string, then JSON.parse(t) to turn it into JSON.

Or try [angular.toJson(t)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)

Comment: var j= JSON.stringify(t);
console.log(JSON.parse(j));

that printed [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

First to save inside cookies

```
 var x= angular.toJson($scope.twotap_builtin_cart);
 $cookies['xxx']= x;
```

To retrieve from cookies

```
 var t = $cookies['xxx'];
 var pota = angular.fromJson(t);
 console.log(pota);
```

It should work for all similar format json data. But for my case the data is too big. So i could not save inside cookies. Now i am using localstorage. First use $window service and inject $window inside controller. 
To set

```
  var ret= angular.toJson($scope.twotap_builtin_cart);
  $window.localStorage.setItem('recent',ret);
```

To retrieve

```
   if(angular.isDefined($window.localStorage.getItem('recent')));
        {
        var tem =$window.localStorage.getItem('recent');
        var pota = angular.fromJson(tem);
        console.log(pota);
        }
```